# Extract debug information and store it into a separate file

Tags: gcc

I want to extract debug information from the target build into a separate file.

I know objcpy and strip are GNU Binary utilities that can be used here but I want to know if there is a way to do this using CFLAGs or combination of GCC flags.

My second question is: can I use GCC -s combined with -o to strip the debug info from objfile and store it into another file?

Comment: `-gsplit-dwarf` maybe?

Comment: does this flag work for all platforms including windows and mac? or just linux?

Comment: Obviously from the name, it won't work on a platform where debug info does not use dwarf.

Comment: Okay thanks! That's really helpful option but I want something to make it work on linux as well as mac and if possible windows too.

Comment: Is there a way I can .dwo file generated with -gsplit-dwarf and convert into some compatible version for mac or windows? maybe that can help too